# Counting characters in a UTF-8 file

Tags: bash, unix, encoding, utf-8, wc

```
wc -c
```

appears to only do a dumb bytecount, not interpret actual characters with regard for encoding.

How can I get the actual character count?

Comment: I edited your question to clarify that you're looking for character counts, not the byte counts `wc -c` gives you. Feel free to roll back the edit if that's not what you meant...

Answer (score 13):

Use `-m` or `--chars` option.

For example (`text` file contains two Korean characters and newline):

```
falsetru@jmlee12:~$ cat text
안녕
falsetru@jmlee12:~$ wc -c text
7 text
falsetru@jmlee12:~$ wc -m text
3 text
```

According to `wc(1)`:

> ```
>    -c, --bytes
>           print the byte counts
>
>    -m, --chars
>           print the character counts
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse chars, `char`s and bytes. A byte is 8 bits long, and `-c` counts bytes in your file whatever you put in. A `char` in many programming languages is also 8 bits long this is why counting bytes uses `-c`! If you want to count how many characters (chars) of a given alphabet you have in a file, then you need to specify in some way which encoding of chars have been used, and sometimes, that encoding uses more than a byte for a char. Read the manual for `wc`, it will tell you that `-m` will use you current locale (roughly your language/charset preferences) to decode the file and count your chars.